# How to connect Spring Boot with a commercial RDMS like NonStop SQL?

Tags: spring-boot

My project uses NonStop SQL (SQL/MX 3.4) as our RDBMS, a product from HP. I am not able to connect to the data source using Spring Boot's standard practice of defining JDBC URL, user, password inside **application.properties** file.

**application.properties**

spring.datasource.driverClassName = com.tandem.t4jdbc.SQLMXDriver

spring.datasource.url = jdbc:T4SQLMX://url

spring.datasource.username = user

spring.datasource.password = password

**spring.datasource.validationQuery=show tables;**

This is the error

**com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Failed to execute isValid() for connection, configure connection test query (Method com/tandem/t4jdbc/SQLMXConnection.isValid(I)Z is abstract).
o.s.b.a.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup           : Unable to determine jdbc url from datasource**

**org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: JDBC DatabaseMetaData method not implemented by JDBC driver - upgrade your driver; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Method com/tandem/t4jdbc/SQLMXConnection.isValid(I)Z is abstract**

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems that the Java driver for NonStop SQL does not implement the `isValid` method for validating the connection, something like a simple `SELECT 1 FROM DUAL` in Oracle DB.

In order for spring to skip calling the `isValid` method on the connection, provide a custom `validationQuery` parameter with a simple query that can be used to check connection to the database.

For example:

`spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1`

Please replace the query above with the one applicable for your database.

Comment: This did not help. I have updated the post with the contents of application.properties and the error that I am getting.

Comment: Can you share the code for your main class and how you're configuring the datasource